# AngularJS ui-router views with custom data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS app and use the ui-router for routing. One of my pages has two similar sections with the same template and logic (so I hope they can use the same controller). The only difference between them is for example `type` property. Here is simplified fiddle of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/e_gluhotorenko/XeX59/7/.

So Is it possible to provide custom **different** data to the views's scopes ? Something like custom data in states but for views:

```
views: {
    'section1' : {
        templateUrl: 'section.html',
        controller : 'ctrl',
        data : { type: 'type1'}
    },
    'section2' : {
        templateUrl: 'section.html',
        controller : 'ctrl',
        data : { type: 'type2'}
    }
}
```

Or with `ui-view` directive like in `ng-inclide`'s `onload`:

```
<div ui-view="section1" onload="type = 'type1'"></div>
<div ui-view="section2" onload="type = 'type2'"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out that `ui-view` actually has `onload` attribute, it is absent in documentation but is in [API ref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive%3aui-view). So my example from the question works! [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3238/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `ng-init` as in `<div ui-view="section1" ng-init="type = 'type1'"></div>`?
That should work, I would link the angular docs for `ng-init`, but the site seems to be down right now

Comment: I think `ng-init` should be called in the parent scope, so we just initialize `type` from parent scope twice. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/GXLZm/1/

Comment: @e.gluhotorenko your jsfiddle seems to do what i suggested, to call `ng-init` on those 2 divs. I merely wrote just one of the two divs. A jsfiddle is always better though, nice!

Comment: If the latest jsfiddle does not do what I/you would expect, than I think I don't understand the question. What are you trying to accomplish, if the behavior above is not as expected?

Comment: Look, I need to pass different values to `tepmplate1`'s and `tepmplate2`'s scopes. Both these scopes are inherited from `main`scope so that they have access to the `type` property that was initialized in the main scope so that the tepmplate1`'s and the `tepmplate2`'s scopes do not have their own `type`. Is it clearer now ? :)

Comment: I like the ng-init alternative. In the provided fiddle, if you try to do `$scope.someValue = $scope.type;` you will find that `$scope.type` is undefined when you enter the controller. Using `ng-init` you will see the expected output `section type1. Type : type1
section type2. Type : type2`